# py.test aggregate results of multiple test runs

Tags: python, automation, pytest

I'm running a couple of instances of `pytest.main()` and once they are all complete I want to quickly see the failures across all the runs without rooting through all the individual reports. How can I do that?

Do I have to parse the textual reports or can I get py.test to return an object with failure data? (so far as I've seen it just returns an integer)

Comment: Even I have the same question ? Is there a quick or direct way to combine/ aggregate / summarise several different runs of pytest in one single report ?

Comment: pytest.main does not return the test failure count. You will have to parse the output log. Documentation: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#calling-pytest-from-python-code

Comment: You can use an autouse fixture in your test code which will monitor the test status and write it somewhere that you can see in your main python code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Allure reports (https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_pytest) for that.

You can run each pytest.main() with option --alluredir= where each instance has different path, for example /path/to/reports/report1, /path/to/reports/report2.

After all runs are completed, you can generate one combined report by running command allure serve /path/to/reports. More about reports generating here: https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_get_started