# How to create single loggin report from multiple testing files?

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-html

I have several test files and I run them one by one using a .bat file.
The batch file looks like this:

```
py.test --html=Myreport.html -v testfile1.py --tb=short
py.test --html=Myreport.html -v testfile2.py --tb=short
py.test --html=Myreport.html -v testfile3.py --tb=short
```

The problem is that each test run will overwrite Myreport.html report (so in this case the report will contain only tests present in testfile3.py file as those from the other two files were overwritten).

Is there any way to have all the test results in a single HTML file report?
Thanks

Comment: `pytest-html` doesn't support merging reports. You will have to implement it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, is there another way (besides pytest-html) to create a single report from more files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [py.test aggregate results of multiple test runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31078419/py-test-aggregate-results-of-multiple-test-runs)